# GitoLite не дает зайти под root

Tags: ssh

```
ssh root@server.name -p11111
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello gitadmin, this is gitolite 2.3-1 (Debian) running on git 1.9.1
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W  gitolite-admin
    @R_ @W_ repo
Connection to server.name closed.
```

По идее GitoLite должен начать работать только если авторизоваться как пользователь git, но я пытаюсь зайти под root и в итоге GitoLite отклоняет подключение.

Попытка решить с помощью гугла:

```
root@server.name:/ lsof /dev/pts/*
COMMAND   PID USER FD    TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME
systemd-l 373 root 1u    CHR  136,2  0t0       5     /dev/pts/2
systemd-l 373 root 2u    CHR  136,2  0t0       5     /dev/pts/2
```

Это, как я понимаю терминал VNC, через который и выполнена команда, то есть лимит 256 терминалов не исчерпан.

Еще гугл советует перемонтировать `/dev/pts` - не могу выполнить, сервер виртуальный и подключение по VNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

универсальный ответ, без конкретики про пользователя, под которым вы не можете аутентифицироваться по протоколу *ssh*.

1. почему это произошло?

   потому что вы (или скрипты конфигурации пакета *gitolite*) выполнили команду `gl-setup ...` (или `gitolite setup ...`) от имени пользователя, под которым вы сейчас пытаетесь подключиться, и в файл `authorized_keys` этого пользователя (находящийся в каталоге `.ssh` внутри дом. каталога) попала строка вида:

   > command="/usr/share/gitolite/gl-auth-command имя",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ваш-ключ комментарий
2. что делать?

   либо удалить всю эту строку, либо (если `ваш-ключ` всё-таки нужен для аутентификации) удалить в этой строке всё от начала строки до слов `ssh-rsa`, чтобы строка выглядела как:

   > ssh-rsa ваш-ключ комментарий

p.s. можно, конечно, и полностью удалить этот файл, если доступ по находящимся там ключам вам не нужен.

p.p.s. упомянутая команда, вообще-то, должна выполняться от имени того пользователя, под которым вы будете управлять *gitolite*-ом (обычно это пользователь `git` или `gitolite`).

Comment: Вряд ли может возникнуть необходимость оставить ключ от git авторизованным для root, это может оказаться очень вредно, если администратор сервера и администратор репозиториев- это не один и тот же человек :) Но Вы все правильно говорите. Спасибо.

Comment: @ReinRaus, спасибо за уточнение. добавил оговорку про «если ключ всё-таки нужен».